How to layout items in sets of two columns with space around?
I have an array with items, lets say it contains 3, could be more, could be less.
I want them to be layed out like the image below.
My requirements are:

Each "item lane" should be of equal width.
They should be "spaced around".
One iteration over the array of items.

What I have tried so far:
<div class="parent">
  @for (item of items) {
    <div class="item">
      {{ item.name }}
    </div>
  }
</div>

.parent {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

Can I somehow tell CSS or Flexbox to wrap after 2?
Are there other options?


IMO display:grid is the way to go.

You can put your desired spacing into a custom property, and then use Flexbox to set the items width by preventing them to grow or shrink and set the width to half the width without the spacing.


:root {
  --spacing: 6vw;
}

.parent {
  background-color: maroon;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  gap: 0 var(--spacing);
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding: var(--spacing);
}

.item {
  background-color: yellow;
  flex: 0 0 calc(50% - var(--spacing) / 2);
}
<div class="parent">
  <div class="item">Item</div>
  <div class="item">Item</div>
  <div class="item">Item</div>
</div>



